# Do I train an ANN for XOR by adjusting weights as determined by one input and then by next and so on?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, xor

I am trying to train ANN in python for XOR without using libraries. I am unable to get the desired output when I test. There are two places I get stuck -

1. Currently I use 2 inputs, 2 hidden nodes(1 hidden layer) and one output. Do I need to use bias as well for hidden and output neurons?
2. I have 4 set of inputs- [0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]. When I start updating the weights, I do that for one set of input, lets say [0,0]. Then I use the second set [0,1] to update the weight and so on. Once the input set is exhausted, I loop the whole process again for quite a few iterations. Is this the right approach to update weight, i.e. doing it for one input and then the next?

Below is my code for reference. Please let me know where I am wrong?

```
import random

def activation_function(x):
    return 1/(1+pow(2.71828,-x))

def der(x):
    return x*(1-x)

#training data
training_inputs = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
training_outputs = [[0],[1],[1],[0]]
LearningRate = 0.5
bias_h = 0.5
bias_o = 0.5

inodes = len(training_inputs[0])
hnodes = len(training_inputs[0])
onodes = int(len(training_inputs)/len(training_outputs))
lr = LearningRate

wih = []
for i in range(hnodes):
    x = []
    for j in range(inodes):
        x.append(random.random()-0.5)
    wih.append(x) 

who = []
for i in range(onodes):
    x= []
    for j in range(hnodes):
        x.append(random.random()-0.5)
    who.append(x)

inputs = training_inputs
targets = training_outputs


for iteration in range(10000):
    #Feed Forward

    for h in range(len(inputs)):
        hidden_inputs = []
        hidden_outputs = []
        final_inputs = []
        final_outputs = []
        output_errors = []
        localG_op = []
        localG_h = []
        for i in range(hnodes):
            sum = 0
            for j in range(inodes):
                sum += wih[i][j]*inputs[h][j]
            hidden_inputs.append(sum)
            hidden_outputs.append(activation_function(sum))

        for i in range(onodes):
            sum = 0
            for j in range(hnodes):
                sum += who[i][j]*hidden_outputs[j]
            final_inputs.append(sum)
            final_outputs.append(activation_function(sum))


        for j in range(onodes):
            output_errors.append(targets[h][j]-final_outputs[j])

        #Backpropagation
        #Local Gradient at output nodes
        for i in range(onodes):
            localG_op.append(output_errors[i]*der(final_outputs[i]))

        #Weight Adjustment for Hidden to Output synapses
        for i in range(onodes):
            for j in range(hnodes):
                who[i][j] += lr*localG_op[i]*hidden_outputs[j]

        #Local Gradient at output nodes
        for i in range(hnodes):
            sum = 0      
            for k in range(onodes):
                sum += who[k][i]*localG_op[k]
            localG_h.append(der(hidden_outputs[i]*sum))

        #Weight Adjustment for Input to Hidden synapses
        for i in range(hnodes):
            for j in range(inodes):
                wih[i][j] += lr*localG_h[i]*inputs[i][j]

#testing   
test_inputs = [1,0]
hidden_inputs = []
hidden_outputs = []
final_inputs = []
final_outputs = [] 
for i in range(hnodes):   
    sum = 0
    for j in range(inodes):
        sum += wih[i][j]*test_inputs[j]
    hidden_inputs.append(sum)
    hidden_outputs.append(activation_function(sum))

for i in range(onodes):
    sum = 0
    for j in range(hnodes):
        sum += who[i][j]*hidden_outputs[j]
    final_inputs.append(sum)
    final_outputs.append(activation_function(sum))    
print(final_outputs)
```